# Views report for Ubercart Order product totals for date range?

Tags: 7, views, ubercart

I have been trying to create a view that will provide me with the total number of each product SKU ordered within a specified date range. Let's say there were three orders within the specified date range:

```
Order 101
Product ABC - Qty 1
Product XYZ - Qty 3

Order 102
Product ABC - Qty 1
Product XYZ - Qty 0

Order 103
Product ABC - Qty 10
Product XYZ - Qty 2
```

The View result would look something like this:

```
Total Number Ordered Per SKU for (date range)
Product ABC - 12
Product XYZ - 5
```

It is important for the results to be based on the SKU of the product, not the product title.

I have played around a bit with Views Aggregation on a "Type: Orders" view, but I am not knowledgeable enough to make it do what I need to do. Perhaps there is an easier way?

The purpose of this view will be to have an "at-a-glance" of which products need to be prepared for fulfillment, and how many of each, for the filtered date range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I used the Views Aggregator Plus module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator). I applied "Group and Compress" and "Tally Members" in the "Group Aggregation" column within the Views Aggregator Table options for the SKU field, and I applied "Sum" in the "Column Aggregation" column for the Quantity field. This provided me with the exact result I was looking for.